# Graph API - User Feed. Photo Posts no longer contain "picture" property?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo

Awhile back, I built a little widget for a client that pulled the "photo" status updates from his feed. Until today, all of the "photo" type posts contained a "picture" property which contained the URL for the small image. As of today this property doesn't seem to be present in the feed. I'm aware that I can hit the graph api again with the objectID and get all of the images for that post, but I'd prefer not to hit the API multiple times.

Did Facebook inadvertently break something here or was this an unannounced change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd still love to hear other solutions if anyone else runs into this problem, but I ended up having to workaround this issue. My solution was to create a server side script that'll grab the original wall feed, then hit the API again for each photo post so I could reconstruct (and cache) an object with the data I need.

---

Followup - it looks like there was a bug, it just took a week to show up on the developer site. It doesn't sound like it's 100% fixed yet either.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/310612805658295

Answer (score 1):

If removed, they didn't document the change here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

However, I just ran `me/feed?fields=from,picture` and I see the picture field appearing for posts that contain a photo.

Comment: When I view my personal feed, the photo posts are showing the picture property as well, but it has disappeared from this user's feed. Wondering if there is a security setting the user could have enabled that is causing this?

Comment: Yes, that might be the case.  Also check the access token in the linter to see if the permissions are set appropriately.

Comment: Sorry man- Good suggestions, but I was unable to resolve the issue directly. I ended up having to grab the original wall feed, then hit the api again for each photo and reconstruct an object that contained all of the data points.

Comment: It's strange that `me/feed?fields=from,picture` doesn't work for you like it does for me.  Happy coding. can you add your solution as an answer and then in 24 hrs accept your own answer so this question closes?

Comment: Will do. My assumption is that Facebook changed the profile feed for fan pages. I wasn't able to reproduce the issue on any other account even with identical security settings, but I didn't try creating another fan page. Thanks again for your help.